# on the inverse of trigonometric or/ and hyperbolic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, logarithms, inverse-function

If we want to find, say, the inverse $\tan$ function, $\tan^{-1}$, in terms of (complex) logarithm function we start with the equation $z=\tan w =\frac{\sin w}{\cos w}=\frac{1}{i}\frac{e^{iw}-e^{-iw}}{e^{iw}+e^{-iw}}$, and solve it for $w$, which gives $e^{2iw}=\frac{i-z}{i+z}$.

I have a doubt exactly at this stage: In the last equation if we take the logarithm of both sides, then we get $\log (e^{2iw})=\log\left(\frac{i-z}{i+z}\right)$. From this point on I saw in many books saying that

$$2iw=\log\left(\frac{i-z}{i+z}\right)\tag1$$

(and so that $w=\frac {1}{2i}\log\left(\frac{i-z}{i+z}\right)$). However in general we have that $\log (e^{2iw})\neq 2iw$. My question is that how do we get the equality $(1)$ from $\log (e^{2iw})=\log\left(\frac{i-z}{i+z}\right)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must keep in mind that $\log$ is not a function. In fact, every $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ has infinitely many logarithms. To be more precise, if $w$ is *a* logarithm of $z$, then$$\{\text{logarithms of }z\}=\{w+2k\pi i\,|\,k\in\mathbb Z\}.$$

In particular $\log e^z=\log w$ simply means that $z$ itself is *a* logarithm of $w$.

Comment: What do you mean when saying "some"? Could you please write your answer a  bit more explicitly?

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: I think that $log (e^{2iw})=\{2iw+i2n\pi: n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, and since the sets $\log(\frac{i-z}{i+z})$ ,   $\log(\frac{i-z}{i+z})+i2n\pi$, are the same, as a consequence we get (1). Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Although my above statement is true, now I really see what you mean: Given a fixed $z\in\mathbb{C}$ , the set of solutions for the equation $e^w=z$ is $\{ln|z|+i(Argz+2nπ):n \in\mathbb{Z}\}$, which is denoted by $logz$, and although $w$ is a member of the set $logz$, notationally, we write $w=logz$. Now, substituting $w$ by $2iw$ and $z$  by $\frac{i−z}{i+z}$, exactly in the same sense we get $2iw\in log(\frac{i−z}{i+z})$, or, by the usual notation, $2iw=log(\frac{i−z}{i+z})$. What was misleading for me is the statement "taking logarithm of both sides". Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.